# Base64 encoding string in Java doubles its length

Tags: java, python, base64

**Problem**

I am trying to encode file contents of doc/pdf extensions to Base64 string in Java.
The encoded string length almost doubles from the original(115k -> 230k).
Whereas encoding the same file contents in Python/PHP or any online tool only gives a third increase(115k -> 154k).

What causes this increase in size for Java and is there any way to get equivalent result as the other sources?

**Code**

```
import java.util.Base64;
...

        //String content;
        System.out.println(content.length());
        String encodedStr = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(content.getBytes()));
        System.out.println(encodedStr.length());
        String urlEncodedStr = new String(Base64.getUrlEncoder().encode(content.getBytes()));
        System.out.println(urlEncodedStr.length());
        String mimieEncodedStr = new String(Base64.getMimeEncoder().encode(content.getBytes()));
        System.out.println(mimieEncodedStr.length());
```

**Output**

For pdf file

115747
230816
230816
236890

For doc file

13685
26392
26392
27086

Comment: How long is `content.getBytes()`?

Comment: content.getBytes().length is 173112 for pdf file

Answer (score 1):

First, **never** use `new String`. Second, pass an **encoding** to [`String.getBytes(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.lang.String)) (e.g. `content.getBytes(encoding)`). For example,

```
String encodedStr = Base64.getEncoder()
        .encodeToString(content.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

or

```
String encodedStr = Base64.getEncoder()
        .encodeToString(content.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
```

Comment: I think of the three prominent ones, you picked the two that don't work well: https://repl.it/repls/UntrueExemplaryRecovery#Main.java

Comment: UTF-8 is probably causing their problem and US-ASCII appears to turn everything non-ASCII into byte 63 (which is the question mark). Kinda dangerous. I would've expected an exception thrown. And probably they just shouldn't have a `String` in the first place...

Comment: @superbrain Java String is UTF-16 (by default). PHP is `ISO-8859-1` and python is `UTF-8`. The obvious explanation for doubling of output size is UTF-16 encoding from Java. Beyond that I wouldn't care to speculate too much.

Comment: See the comments under the question. 173112 isn't twice as much as as 115747. Only about 1.5 times as much, as you'd expect from UTF-8 and uniformly distributed characters 0-255. And 173112 multiplied by 4/3 (what you'd expect from base64) is exactly their result size 230816.

Comment: Then you are correct. The entire sequence OP is using to populate their `String` is suspect.

Comment: Btw UTF-16 as far as I know is Java's *internal* encoding. Not what gets used by `getBytes` (which the doc says uses "the platform's default charset").

Comment: Note that that signature of `getBytes` throws a checked exception; `StandardCharsets` has constants for those character sets.

Comment: I used `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(content.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1))` to get resulting string of 154k length. `getBytes("UTF-8")` also resulted in 230k. The charsets being same in encodeToString and getBytes produced expected result.